# Maping res from mongo db... Out of order.. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, fetch

I am unsure how to fix this mapping problem... I thought ES6 always maps in order.. but I think something funky is happening? Can you help. Heres a description... and the code..

First I fetch an array of IDs from Mongo DB in my componentDidMount function. 
This list comes in the same order Every time. I have checked.

I pass the array of IDs to my second function, convertIdToCard... This function maps through the array and fetches information from mongoDB from each ID. This is where things are getting out of order.

The fetch returns an object for each ID that was mapped from the original array. It pushes the Object to a new array. This array stays in the same order as the original array about 80% of the time... and 20% the array is not in the same order.

I added the setTimeout to the second function... it helps but its still not right 100% of the time.

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/autoquotegenerators/${this.state._id}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.convertIdToCard(res.quoteGenerator)
            console.log(res.quoteGenerator)
        });
}


convertIdToCard(quoteCards){
    quoteCards.map(id => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/autoquotegenerators/${id}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                // console.log(res.quoteGenerator[0].cardType)
                this.createQuoteCards(res.quoteGenerator);
                console.log(res.quoteGenerator)
            })
        },1000)
        })
}
```

Here is my new Code ---

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/autoquotegenerators/${this.state._id}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.convertIdToCard(res.quoteGenerator)
            console.log(res.quoteGenerator)
        });
}


convertIdToCard(quoteCards){
    const selfMap = (quoteCards) => {
        if(quoteCards.length > 0){
            fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/autoquotegenerators/${quoteCards.shift()}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                // console.log(res.quoteGenerator[0].cardType)
                this.createQuoteCards(res.quoteGenerator);
                console.log(res.quoteGenerator)
                selfMap(quoteCards);
            })
        }else {
            console.log('done')
        }
    }
    selfMap(quoteCards);       
}
```

Comment: You have a couple of layers of async going on there.  The `map` should be running in order, so the `setTimeout` creates those timers in order.  But the timers could be firing in batches, and when the timer callback executes it also calls the async `fetch`, and the `createQuoteCards` and `console.log` are called when each fetch promise executes the `then`, which may or may not be in the same order as they were initiated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Joe! Hmm I see how the setTimeout can fire in batches...  Do you think I need to take the setTimeout away and do something else? I am now reading about using async and await inside of a map function - I guess my question is how do I make sure the createQuoteCards function gets fired before it moves to the second ID in the array?

Comment: Don't create a bunch of timers all at the same time.  Instead create a recursive function that passes the entire array to the callback sent to setTimeout, and use 0 for the timeout so it fires and gets on the stack immediately after the current function.  The callback should pop the first element of the array and process it, then call the function with the remainder of the array during the `then from the `fetch` so a new timer is created.  That way you only have 1 fetch in flight at any given time, so you know they are processed in order.

Comment: Woah! Ok! I will work on this and see what happens! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey Joe! Here is what I have so far - It seems to be working! Let me know what you think - I'd love your input.

Comment: I added the code to the original post